# How to install Node.js only if needed (not already installed) on a vagrant shell?

Tags: node.js, shell, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm using vagrant shell provisioning here.
I've installed on my vm Node.js along with many other packages.
I want to avoid running parts in my provisioning script when I don't need them.
For example - I already successfully installed via my script Node.js & nginx, so when I want to add additional packages like mysql or redis, I want to add it to the script, I want to run the script to test that it runs properly, but I DO NOT want to re-install Node.js or nginx again...
I need a simple conditional statement that would detect if a package is already installed, and install it only if it is not already installed.
Is there a generic check or will it be different from package to package?
Thanks
Ajar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dpkg -s <pkg-name> 2>/dev/null >/dev/null || sudo apt-get -y install <pkg-name>
```

This should be what you're looking for.

**What's going on here:**
This is a conditional assignment of the form `<condition> && <value if true> || <value if false>`

The first part of the expression uses dpkg to check to if the package is installed, suppressing the output. The second part is evaluated if the condition returns false. The "true" case is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

This dependes on the Linux distribution you are using. Usually, a package manager comes with some kind of mechanism to skipp already installed packages.

For Ubuntu, this is built in - running `apt-get install nodejs` with Node.js already installed will not reinstall it; it will skip the target (unless there is new version available)

For ArchLinux, you can add run `pacman -Sy node --needed` to skip already installed packages.

A platform-independent mechanism would be to check if the executable (or any other known file for that package) exists. In Bash, you can do:

`which node > /dev/null && echo "Yup, this is installed"`

(the `> /dev/null` part supresses `which`'s output - it prints the path where the found executable resides; we do not care about that, we only want to know if it is installed)

If you want to avoid writing custom Bash scripts for such basic checks I can recommend that you configure your boxes with tools dedicated for exactly what you are trying to achieve. The usual suspects here are:

- [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home)
- [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com)
- [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef)
- [CFEngine](http://cfengine.com)

All of these are supported by Vagrant so integrating them should not be a problem. You can find detailed guides on integrating these into your existing Vagrant recipe [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html).

PS. For a simple exapmle you can check out my [Ansible provisioning recipe](https://github.com/Alaneor/pi-server) for Banana Pi machine running ArchLinux (note: it does not really follow best practices, but it might be a good starting point). There are many examples available online, check them out, too.

Comment: Hi Robert & thank you for your reply!  
I use ubuntu, and for packages installed with apt-get it's good to know it checks existing packages automatically. However some of the packages are being installed from source (like node js and others in my case), so I cannot rely only on that. your "which" line is just great for me, i just need the rest... if a package doesn't - install it. I'm a beginner with bash script.
Ansible will be my choice after inspecting the different orchestration tools, but I will go into it when I'll scale.

Comment: Right now I just want to create the simple deployment workflow and cannot afford yet another learning curve. For me it's an overkill right now, although these tools look amazing. So does Docker - machine / compose / swarm, CoreOS etcd / systemd / fleet, Mesos Zookeeper etc... it never ends...   
all I really need right now just to get going is a simple bash "if" statement that checks if a package is already installed on my ubuntu server and installs it if it doesn't, can you please help me with that?
Cheers and thanks again Robert!

Comment: Perhaps [Bash tutorial on IF](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_07.html) will be helpful?

Comment: Hey Robert, look - I'm missing the bash basics - defining vars, if statements etc... this is why I posted my question.
For anybody experienced with bash script this should take two seconds.  
My silly attempt:   
which node > MY_NODE_VER  
if [  MY_NODE_VER -ne null ]  
 then  
    echo "I Should install node"  
fi